# How to remove an effect from a time series

Tags: regression, time-series, covid-19

I have two time series data sets.  The first is a population over time and the second is a normalized COVID effect factor over time.  What I want to do is remove the COVID effect from my first time series using the second time series. I am curious how I would do that.  I believe I can take the following steps, but I am wondering if there is something more robust or better.

1.) Create regression model with data before covid to forecast the future
2.) Use future data along with covid effect effect data to fit to data that includes covid

Comment: Can you explain more about the question and causal model? In joint, multivariate modeling we rarely think about "subtracting" out the effect of a single, isolated covariate, because the effect depends on the other covariate(s) included in the model.

Comment: @AdamO Yes - It's a single time series in which I'm trying to remove the "covid effect" by using another time series

Comment: So fit a regression, and then calculate the residuals?

Comment: @AdamO, follow up question, so we only need to perform a regression using the two dataset, calculate its residual and subtract this residual in the 1st data set to remove the covid effect?